# Exclude multiple elements from a DOM query using a variable

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="elem">
</div>
<div class="elem-1">
</div>
<div class="elem-2">
</div>

<!--Select the ones below-->
<div>
</div>
<p class="other-class">
</p>
```

I have this code:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".elem, .elem-1, .elem-2[,...]");
var otherElems = document.querySelectorAll(":not..."); //can I reuse elems here?
```

Can I use the `elems` variable to select all elements except for the ones in `elems`?

EDIT: This seems like code duplication:

```
var foos1 = document.querySelectorAll(".bars1, .bars2, .bars3, #bar1, #bar2[,...]");
var foos2 = document.querySelectorAll(".bars-1, .bars-2, .bars-3, #bar-1[,...]");
var foos3 = ...
.
.
.
var foosN

//list all former elements again
var noFoos = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.bars1, ..., .bars-3, #bar-1......)");
```

Instead I would like to reuse the variables I stored these elements in already.

Something like:

```
var noFoos = document.querySelectorAllBut(foos1, foos2, foos3,...);
```

Comment: Which elements do you want to "exclude"? Can you include HTML at Question?

Comment: The ones with the classes in the first querySelectorAll arguments list. It's a hypothetical page. Maybe the question isn't that clear....

Comment: No, the Question is not clear. How do you know if the pattern is correct or not if the question is hypothetical?

Comment: I guess it's clearer now and no longer hypothetical: https://jsfiddle.net/deq4dfL1/#&togetherjs=z109PPnFdr

Comment: Which elements should be excluded from `elems` when defining `otherElems`?

Comment: No, the Question is not clearer. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the first selector inside the `not`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".elems, .elems-more, .elems-more-more[,...]");
var otherElements = querySelectorAll("div:not(.elems, .elems-more, .elems-more-more[,...])");
```

Also, you could put the selector in a variable to avoid duplication. This might not be the most efficient solution, though.